# binarySearch with generics and capture of

Tags: java, generics

I have a Task:

```
public interface Task {
}
```

Then I have implementations for those:

```
public interface Task__Init extends Task {
    void init(Element e);
}

public interface Task__Hit_Test extends Task {
    boolean hit_test(Element e, float x, float y);
}

public interface Task__Draw extends Task {
    void draw(Element e);
}
```

I also have a class that can hold a instance of those implementations:

```
static public class Task_Holder<T extends Task> {
    public int task_id;
    public Task_Type type;
    public T task;
    // ...
}
```

Then I have a class that holds those, where the last ArrayList holds all of them (all_task_holders)

```
static public class Implementation_Context {
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Task_Holder<Task__Init>>>     init_solvers = new HashMap<>();
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Task_Holder<Task__Draw>>>     draw_solvers = new HashMap<>();
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Task_Holder<Task__Hit_Test>>> hit_test_solvers = new HashMap<>();

    public ArrayList<Task_Holder<? extends Task>> all_task_holders = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
}
```

Now one of the problem arises:

```
static public Task_Holder<?> find_task_holder(int task_id) {

    Comparator<Task_Holder<?>> comparator = (a, b)-> {
        if (a.task_id < b.task_id) return -1;
        if (a.task_id > b.task_id) return 1;
        return 0;
    };

    Collections.sort(ctx.implementation.all_task_holders, comparator);

    Task_Holder<?> key = new Task_Holder<>();
    key.task_id = task_id;

    int index = Collections.binarySearch(ctx.implementation.all_task_holders, key);

    for (Task_Holder<?> th : ctx.implementation.all_task_holders) {
        if (th.task_id == task_id) {
            return th;
        }
    }
    assert false; // should we find things that are not there?
    return null;
}
```

For the binarySearch I get (I make it a codeblock here, else stackoverflow removes words for some reason?):

> ```
> The method binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>,
> T) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments
> (ArrayList<sfjl_ui.Task_Holder<?>>, sfjl_ui.Task_Holder<capture#6-of
> ?>)
> ```

I have no clue how to fix this. Every attempt breaks other things (for example I break the sort that's 3 lines higher).
It feels like paying off credit card debts with other credit cards, you never win.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you haven't implemented `Comparable` on the `Task_Holder` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the comparator [as an additional argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-):

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(ctx.all_task_holders, key, comparator);
```